# Adjustable steel column is raised too high - can I lower it?

Tags: crawlspace, steel, column

Refer to image: The red beam you see overhead in the picture (which runs perpendicular to the other beam) is directly underneath a hump which runs from the bathroom, into the hallway, and into the hallway closet.  It is a fairly large hump at nearly 1/2" above the floor.

Question I have is, can I simply lower the support using the lug at the top of the threads or do I need to enlist the help of a professional?  This is under 3 levels of condo units. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this sort of structural work needs on-site professional eyeballs

Comment: Especially in a MDU...but the question does, in part, ask if a professional should be enlisted - and the answer is YES!!!

Answer (score 3):

Jacking buildings looks simple, but can be complex. I've done quite bit of it for a non-professional, but I happen to be related to a Licensed Professional Civil Engineer who directed the work I've done. As a brash youngster I often could not quite see why we had to take it so slowly - as a somewhat more experienced adult I grasp the fact that you can break a building by jacking it incorrectly.

With "**3 levels of condo on top**" you'd be well past "fool" and into "darned fool" territory not to have any such work guided by a Licensed Professional Engineer. It only looks simple.

There's also the pesky possibility that the column is right where it should be and other parts of the foundation are sinking.